# OpenCV Perspective Transform (potentially) not producing the correct output

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to perform a perspective transform in OpenCV, and I have the following at present:

```
new_doc_coords = [[  72  477]
                  [ 544  477]
                  [  93 1163]
                  [ 532 1177]]

new_box_coords = [[  72  477]
                  [ 544  477]
                  [  72 1163]
                  [ 544 1163]]

# Perspective Transform
resmatrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(new_doc_coords), np.float32(new_box_coords))
trans_bgr_img = cv2.warpPerspective(rotated_bgr_img, resmatrix, (rotated_bgr_img.shape[1], rotated_bgr_img.shape[0]), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Calculate new_doc_coords
doc_coords_aug = np.hstack((new_doc_coords, np.ones((new_doc_coords.shape[0], 1))))
new_doc_coords = rot_mat.dot(doc_coords_aug.T).T.astype(int)
top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right = sort_points(new_doc_coords)
print(sort_points(new_doc_coords))

[[  72  469]
 [ 543  484]
 [  71 1155]
 [ 509 1183]]
```

According to my understanding, sort_points(new_doc_coords) should be equal to new_box_coords because the image is supposed to be stretched/distorted such that new_doc_coords = new_box_coords, but evidently, this is not the case. I have also tried with different interpolation methods, but this does not resolve the issue.

- Tried different interpolation methods
- Expected sort_points(new_doc_coords) = new_box_coords

Comment: [mre] required. parts of the code missing. specifically the part that chops off the third dimension after matrix multiplication. you should have looked at those values. they're not `1`. "sort points" sounds like a bad idea on top of everything.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thank you for your response. I excluded the other portions of the code because I felt it was too long and irrelevant for this purpose. Specifically, it pertains to how new_doc_coords and new_box_coords is computed. Also, after the matrix multiplication, I don't think (or see) the 3rd dimension is being chopped off i.e., I don't see any slicing taking place. sort_points is not compulsory, it is just a function that sorts the coordinates in the following order: top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right. Why would this be a bad idea?